# Angular CLI RTMP Video player not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, video, video-streaming, rtmp

I've been trying to stream a rtmp video on Angular, but for some reason it doesn't work

my code is

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}">
  <source src="video_rtmp_url" type="rtmp/mp4">
</video>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19.2/video.js"></script>
```

The result I get is this:
[image]

Obs: I've ran the "npm install --save videojs" command

Obs²: i'm using ruby on rails on the background, there's no direct relation between it and the video player yet, but on the rails views, the exact same code works fine

Obs³: There's no error or something related on the console

Besides that, what are the other options to stream RTMP on Angular?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5  tag does not support RTMP protocol.

RTMP was originally an Adobe protocol and flash players did support it.

Some HTML5 Javascript based video players, such as video.js that you are using, will support RTMP, but they generally do this by falling back to flash so you must have flash installed and available for it to work in this case.

Comment: I have flash installed, as I said, the exact same code works fine on Ruby on Rails' views, do I need to install a plugin or something related to make it work on Angular?

Comment: Its hard to say without console output which you say you are not getting, but there are some fairly well used libraries for using videojs with Angular - the one seems the most popular: https://github.com/LonnyGomes/vjs-video